# What does += %w mean in the line used to precompile assets in assets.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking at the default file placed in `/config/initializers/assets.rb` in a Rails 5 app.

To precompile code, Rails inside the comments, gives a pre-existing code to precompile assets together.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

I am curious what the last part means: `+= %w( search.js )`, as I have never seen the expression (`+= %w`) used in Ruby or Rails. I know that the entire line is calling the Rails class, chaining some methods together to create the end output. But I am curious, what does the += %w do, and how is it affecting what I presume to be the argument (`search.js`)?

Comment: `%w` is shorthand for an array of strings, in your case `[ 'search.js' ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

is equal to doing

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = Rails.application.config.assets.precompile + ['search.js']
```

To break it down, `+=` is just the regular operator for including the lefthand side in the statement. Like

```
i = 0
i += 1 # i = i + 1
```

`%w` enables you to create an array like this

```
%w(search.js profile.js error.js)
```

which is just a nice shorthand for

```
['search.js', 'profile.js', 'error.js']
```

Comment: So is Rails.application.config.assets.precompile an array, and you're simply adding to that array via the += %w?

Comment: @the12 That's correct.